# Making a structure game without cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i would like to know how to work in Xcode a structure game without use any framework.
I mean, i want to have an intro splash, then a menu screen with different options ( for example play game, scores, options, credits...). The point of my quedtion is that i guest that i should work each of this items with differents view controllers and views. So how I should call them? With insertView, addSubview, presentModalView?? What's the way to procedd in this cases? 
Is like work with scenes in Cocos but i don' t want to use it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to modify cocos so it wouldn't use the OpenGL view as the only view.

Instead, I'm using UIKit for all the UI, and a special view controller that holds the Cocos OpenGL view for the game.

Comment: Thanks as well. The idea is don't touch cocos, just for learn other way,

Comment: Well, you don't really have modify cocos, but the way cocos adds the view to the application's window; you can do this in the app delegate of the cocos V1 template. I haven't tried it yet with Cocos V2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UINavigationController` to manage a hierarchy of `UIViewController`s. Here is a basic example of how to use it.

First, display your main view controller when the app is launched:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...
    YourMainViewController *mainViewController = [[YourMainViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    // ...
}
```

Then, Let's say a button is pressed in the main view and you want to display the game view:

```
- (void)startGameButtonPressed
{
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Finally, let's say the game is finished and you want to go back to the main view:

```
- (void)goToMainView
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Finally, note that you can create your view hierarchy in Interface Builder too.

Comment: I have been working in your example, and works fine. I learn so much handle the views. Thanks!